# Directive for dynamic background color

Tags: html, angularjs, dynamic, background-color, directive

I have a template with this input

```
<div class="form-group" LayoutDirective="">
                <label>Background color for views</label>
                <input type="text" name="background_color" id="background_color" ng-model="selectedLayout.background_color" class="form-control" />
            </div>
```

and the input gets the value from the spectrum pick color with this code

```
<script>
$("#background_color").spectrum({
    color: "#f00"
}); </script>
```

What I want is when I click on this button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="saveChanges-button" ng-click="saveChanges(selectedLayout)">Save</button>
```

to change my  background-color. I created a directive, but i don't know why doesn't work.
This is my directive:

```
(function() {
angular.module('routerApp').directive('LayoutDirective', function() {
    $('saveChanges-button').click(function() {
        var backgroundColor = $('#background_color').val();
        $('body').css('background-color', backgroundColor);
    });
});
```

})

Comment: As we say Don't mix drink and drive . Same way don't mix jquery and angular.

Comment: http://www.ngroutes.com/questions/AUy0XhXRJGEimGEpEs-q/angularjs-onclick-of-button-i-want-to-change-color-of-another-element.html

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/75a48f/change-background-color-dynamically-using-angularjs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so what you can do here is use ng-style bind to this text scope.

```
 <div ng-app="routerApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
       <div class="form-group" ng-style="{'background-color': color}">
            <label>Background color for views</label>
            <input type="color" name="background_color" id="background_color" ng-model="color" class="form-control" />
        </div>
</div>
```

And if you want to add some default color to it . Specify in controller or ng-init. whatever you like

```
angular.module('routerApp',[]).controller('ctrl',function($scope){
  $scope.color= '#752222';
 });
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gje396o0/)

Comment: Works on the fiddle, but i want to choose my color from spectrum color picker.

Comment: Ok i have update code . Click on fiddle link again .

Comment: Thanks for giving me the example. i have done it like this <div ng-show="themeSelected" ng-style="{'background-color':selectedLayout.background_color;}">
    <form>
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Background color for views</label>
                    <input type="text" name="background_color" id="background_color" ng-model="selectedLayout.background_color" class="form-control" />
                </div>
Bless you.

Comment: Not a problem . if it is satisfactory , you can accept my answer :)